# Restoring "Source Files" and "Header Files" folders

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I don't know how this happened, but I have a project where header and source files are not nicely grouped in "Source Files" and "Header Files" directory in the project hierarchy.

Instead, they all sit directly under the project node.

[image]

I tried to manually add these folders, but their icons look different than the usual icons, so I guess that isn't the way to do it.

How could I restore these folders?

Comment: Those groupings are called filters and are stored in the projects .vcxproj.filters file. Have you accidentally deleted that file, and can you retrieve it from Windows recycle bin or from source control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't folders per se.

What you're looking for are *filters*, which help organize code without the need of folders.

They're commonly used for separating header files from implementation files.

[image: Adding a filter]

Comment: In an Ok project it shows "New Filter', in my messed up project it shows 'News Folder"... Why? Please update your answer, if you know

Comment: @DmitryBabich, you should disable "Show All Files" mode to be able to add filters instead of folders.

Comment: Thank you. In the case of tmighty, who asked that question, I believe it is just fine pressing 'Show All Files' to restore what was accidentally messed up. Create Filters is not necessary

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid, the accepted answer is irrelevant. All you need to do is to select your messed up project in the solution explorer, then find and click the "Show All Files" button. When you pressed it the first time, your filters were gone. If you press it again, it goes back.

[image]

Comment: The accepted answer is also relevant for someone, who really deleted filters.